# Angular material table displaying empty rows

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I'm trying to integrate Angular's material table in a new project but for some reason the data is not displayed, only the empty rows. I used the same logic in another project and there it works, I spent a lot of time to find the reason but nothing works.

I need to add the table in a lazy loaded module called "**cores**" and I imported the material table module:

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoresRoutingModule,
    MatTableModule
  ]
```

I created a services which returns an array of "ICore" objects:

```
getCores(): Observable<ICore[]> {
    return this.http.get<ICore[]>('/cores');
  }
```

The **ICore** interface:

```
export interface ICore {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

The HTML from my "**index.component.html**" file:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let core"> {{ core.id }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let core"> {{ core.name }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

The logic from "index.components.ts" file:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ICore>();
columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'name'];

constructor(private coreService: CoreService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.coreService.getCores().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.dataSource.data = res;
        console.log(this.dataSource);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

From my console.log I see that the dataSource is populated:

```
MatTableDataSource {_renderData: BehaviorSubject, _filter: BehaviorSubject, _internalPageChanges: Subject, _renderChangesSubscription: Subscriber, sortingDataAccessor: ƒ, …}
data: Array(3)
0: {id: 1, name: "core1"}
1: {id: 2, name: "core2"}
2: {id: 3, name: "core3"}
```

I also tried this method:

```
dataSource = new CoreDataSource(this.coreService);
columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'name'];

constructor(private coreService: CoreService) { }

export class CoreDataSource extends DataSource<any> {   
    constructor(private coreService: CoreService) {
        super();
    }

  connect(): Observable<ICore[]> {
    console.log(this.coreService.getCores());
    return this.coreService.getCores();   }

  disconnect() {} }
```

But with the same result. I feel that is something stupid that I forget to do but I don't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your template you use `displayedColumns` for the columns but in your component the variable is called `columnsToDisplay`. Is that a typo in your question or an actual error in the code?

Comment: OMG. I'm so embarrassed, I checked everything but not this variable name. It solved the problem. thank you!. You can add an answer and I will mark it as solved.

Comment: Happens to the best of us, sometimes all you just need is just another pair of eyes to look over your code.

Comment: @FabianKüng, You are right. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you use the same variable to display the columns that you defined in your component.

**Component:**

```
columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'name'];
```

**Template:**

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></mat-row>
```

Comment: thanks man, I'm using angular 5. Documentation says <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr> <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>. It was showing nothing

Answer (score 0):

Since your data source is in a sub variable data it wont render this way. Try the following code

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource.data">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let core"> {{ core.id }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let core"> {{ core.name }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: Same result... it this would be the problem it would with the second solution that I tried.. :(

Comment: Have you tries this.dataSource = res;

Comment: Yes but in this case an error is displayed: Type 'ICore[]' is missing the following properties from type 'MatTableDataSource<ICore>'